# HttpUrlConnection.setConnectTimeout() not workig for java class

Tags: java, http, timeout, httpurlconnection

```
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
con.setConnectTimeout(10000);
con.setReadTimeout(10000);

String urlparameters = "{...}";
con.setOutPut(true);

try(DataOutPutStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream())){
wr.writebytes(urlparameters);
wr.flush();
}
catch(Exception e){
system.out.println(e.getmessage());
}

int responsocode = con.getResponsecode();
```

I am also using setconnecttimeout() out and setredtimeout() but still not getting 200 responsecode.
getting timeout exception message.

Is there any other possible reason?

Comment: What is the message you're exactly receiving when your call fails ? Because you can encounter a timeout for many reasons : among them, the remote site failed to handle your request, isn't here, not on that port, etc.

Comment: The issue has been resolved. It was occurring due to firewall issue. Thank you.